# Checking if the fund is sufficient

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am currently doing an ATM Management System, I want my program to check if the amount entered does not exceed the account's balance on database. Here is my code:

```
Dim w As Double
w = Val(txtwithdraw.Text)

adapter = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `balance` FROM `jaagbank` WHERE 
       acctnum = '" & Form1.namebox.Text & "'", con)
dtable.Clear()
adapter.Fill(dtable)

If w > dtable.Rows.Count Then
    MsgBox("Insufficient Balance")
    txtwithdraw.Clear()
    Return
End If
```

Comment: First, you need to make sure that a value was returned, i.e. check the value of `dtable.Rows.Count` is not 0. Assuming you don't care if more than one row was returned, you then need to check the value of the first cell (index 0) of the first row (index 0). N.B. You really should use an SQL parameter for the value of Form1.namebox.Text as otherwise it will break if someone has an apostrophe in their name, like "T'Pau".

Comment: I would expect the row count to be 1. So the maximum withdrawal amount has to less than  or equal to 1?

Answer (score 1):

`Decimal` is a good datatype to used for money. Don't use the vb6 `Val()`. You can get unexpected results. Put `Option Strict` and `Option Infer` on. I used `.TryParse` to test the input in `txtwithdraw`. If it returns `True`, it puts the converted decimal value in `WithdrawalAmount`.

Keep your data objects local to the method where they are used. Connections and commands need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for us even if there is an error.

**Always** use parameters to avoid sql injection. If the code is running in `Form1`, do not qualify `namebox` with `Form1`. It seems a bit strange that a field named `acctnum` is not a number but a `String` containing a name. You will need to check your database for the correct datatype and field size. I had to guess.

Since you are retrieving a single piece of data, you can use `.ExecuteScalar` which will give you the first column of the first row.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim WithdrawalAmount As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtwithdraw.Text, WithdrawalAmount) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid withdrawal amount.")
        Return
    End If
    Dim Balance As Object
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
        cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT `balance` FROM `jaagbank` WHERE acctnum = @Name;", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Form1.namebox.Text
        con.Open()
        Balance = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    End Using

    If Balance Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Account not recognized.")
        Return
    End If
    If WithdrawalAmount > CDec(Balance) Then
        MsgBox("Insufficient Balance")
        txtwithdraw.Clear()
        Return
    End If
End Sub
```